# Silverlight Ria services authentication on Azure

Tags: silverlight, authentication, azure, wcf-ria-services

I have spent many hours trying to get my Silverlight Business application to run on Azure. My findings so far (open to correction)

1. Asp net authentication works with a Silverlight web application but not if Ria services is added. This is because Azure only allows one form of authentication per hosting and WCF will not work if the authentication mode is not Anonymous. This mean using WebContext is out of the question.
2. For the same reason passive federated claims authentication (either OpenID or custom STS)  will not work with Ria services.
3. There is some good stuff in the Identity Training Kit. Active federated claims should allow a login popup to by used. Again there is an example in the kit. I initially didn't look at the "Out of Browser" example until I realised that it should work In Browser as well. I created a custom STS which the Web app called successfully, but I got "service not found" - I assume on the return leg.
4. I have now decided to pull the plug on all this as I need to get my application up and running. The Silverlight client already communicates with my database via Ria Services - why do I need to create extra pipelines when the authentication data is going to be in the same database? Would security be comprimised by simply checking a user name and password against my database? Would the System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.ApplicationServices namespace be useful in this?

Comment: Have you looked at either of these posts? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/06/09/ria-and-windows-azure.aspx or http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/06/09/ria-and-sql-azure.aspx. I got the Business Application running in both.

Answer (score 1):

Second statement in your list is not accurate. You can use claims based identity with Ria Services. See here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eugeniop/archive/2009/11/22/updated-ria-and-wif-samples.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eugeniop/archive/2009/11/25/ria-services-and-wif-part-ii.aspx